# Braintree drop-in auto-reload despite paymentMethodNonceReceived

Tags: javascript, forms, braintree

So I have a single-page app, and a braintree drop-in located on the register page. There is an option for a free account, so I do not have the form that the drop-in is inside as the main form of the page.

So I have a form like this:

```
<form id="payment-form">
    <div id="payment-box"></div>
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;"/>
</form>
```

I have a handler on the form to prevent the form from submitting, and in my braintree setup, I've defined a `paymentMethodNonceReceived` handler, but when I trigger the form, the page reloads, depending on the url. If you watch the log, `paymentMethodNonceReceived` is not triggered.

For instance, my url for register is `domain.com/#!/register` but when the form is triggered, it reloads to `domain.com/?#!/register` which I understand is usually the same page, but not with a single-page app like this. this triggers page reload and resets all my registration fields. If you run this again from the `?#!` version of the url, then it works as expected, no reload and the handler is triggered. I do not want to add a `?` to my url just for this.

I really like the drop-in and feel like this *should* work, but it sounds like I'm going to have to do a custom implementation. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't fully understand why this was the issue, but my `e.preventDefault` on my submit wasn't triggering because I was sending the form with:

```
$('#payment-form input[type="submit"]').click();
```

instead of something like

```
$('#payment-submit').click();
```

The first one still submits the form, no matter what. Had nothing to do with Braintree.

Comment: Could you show how u implemented the js part please? Having some issues implementing DROPIN UI with angularjs

Comment: @iTenzo make a new question! I don't really have any experience with Angular, but I'm sure you'll get an answer if you ask.